# TouchableOpacity not firing on expo react native

Tags: react-native

I'm not sure why TouchableOpacity is not working in a map.
Here is my code:

```
     <Content>
        <Form>
          <Header>
            <Title>{concernName}</Title>
          </Header>
            { values.map(value => (
              <TouchableOpacity
              key={value.id}
              onPress={() => console.log('pressed')}
              style={styles.touchable}>
              <ListItem>
                <CheckBox />
                  <Text style={styles.bodyTextOptions}>{value.name}</Text>
              </ListItem>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            )) }
        </Form>
      </Content>
```

To confirm the placement of the TouchableOpacity I've added the style:

```
  touchable: {
    width: '100%',
    backgroundColor: '#e5edf9',
    margin: 10,
    height: 55
  },
```

This produces the following:
[image]

When I click on the blue area, nothing happens.  I get no error just nothing happens.
Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up getting this to work by eliminating the TouchableOpacity.  For some reason the TouchableOpacity wasn't working with a nested checkbox.

```
            { values.map(value => (
              <ListItem key={value.id} onPress={ () => console.log('pressed') }>
                <CheckBox checked={ this.activateCheckBox(item) }/>
                <Body>
                  <Text style={styles.bodyTextOptions}>{value.name}</Text>
                </Body>
              </ListItem>
            )) }
```

With the above I can check the whole row and also check the checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

In such case you can use `TouchableOpacity` from `'react-native-gesture-handler'` package instead of `'react-native'` package

Answer (score 0):

Please check your import statement and make sure that your `TouchableOpacity` is imported from `react-native` and not from `react-native-gesture-handler` because the same thing happens when you import it from `react-native-gesture-handler`

Answer (score -1):

you missed a pair of curly braces in `onPress={() => console.log('pressed')}`
it should be `onPress={() => {console.log('pressed')}}`
what you did is to just return a meaningless value(a function), you should actually call the function with help of curly braces.

Arrow function by default return the value at right side of the arrow, and execute the codes if it's wrapped with curly braces.

Answer (score -1):

[CheckBox interface extends Touchableopacity props](https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/pull/1912) in NativeBase.

So you can call `onPress` in `Touchableopacity` as below,

```
<Content>
    <Form>
        <Header>
            <Title>{concernName}</Title>
        </Header>
        {values.map(value => (
            <TouchableOpacity
                key={value.id}
                onPress={() => console.log('pressed')}
                style={styles.touchable}>
                {/* <ListItem>
                <CheckBox />
                  <Text style={styles.bodyTextOptions}>{value.name}</Text>
              </ListItem> */}
            </TouchableOpacity>
        ))}
    </Form>
</Content>
```

Or you can pass `onPress` as a prop to `CheckBox`

```
<Content>
    <Form>
        <Header>
            <Title>{concernName}</Title>
        </Header>
        {values.map(value => (
            <TouchableOpacity
                key={value.id}
                style={styles.touchable}>
                <ListItem>
                    <CheckBox onPress={() => console.log('pressed')} />
                    <Text style={styles.bodyTextOptions}>{value.name}</Text>
                </ListItem>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        ))}
    </Form>
</Content>
```

Comment: This solution does not work.  The sample code above removes the checkbox button which I want there.  The bottom does the check box works but tthe whole touchable doesn't.  I wouldn't need the TouchableOpacity if I wanted just to use the checkbox button.

Comment: So remove native base use library & create your own Checkbox component.

Comment: I ended up just removing touchable opacity, I can't accept this answer since it technically didn't answer the problem, but thank you for trying!  @SDushan

Comment: @FabricioG there was an issue with the ```Native Base``` I was pointing that issue in my answer. Basically you can't use ```onpress``` in ```TouchableOpacity``` because that extends by ```Native Base CheckBox```.

Comment: my answer might not solve your problem, but it gave you some idea about how ```Native base CheckBox ``` works.